# dart: How to get same data from two List?

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my code. I want here same data from these two list data and data2.
But here I used where function which is giving empty list.
So how to do it please help me, Thank you.

```
   List data =  [
                    {
                       "isin": "ANQ129",
                        "label": "cocoa",
                        "swatch_value": null,
                        "products": [
                            118
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "isin": "ANQ103",
                        "label": "apple",
                        "swatch_value": null,
                        "products": [
                            121,
                            128
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                       "isin": "ANQ150",
                        "label": "milk",
                        "swatch_value": null,
                        "products": [
                            122
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "isin": "ANQ160",
                        "label": "coconut",
                        "swatch_value": null,
                        "products": [
                            130
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "isin": "ANQ123",
                        "label": "cherry",
                        "swatch_value": null,
                        "products": [
                            126
                        ]
                    }
                ];
    List data2 =  [
                    {
                       "isin": "ANQ129",
                        "label": "cocoa",
                        "swatch_value": null,
                        "products": [
                            118
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                       "isin": "ANQ128",
                        "label": "dark chocolate",
                        "swatch_value": null,
                        "products": [
                            120,
                            127
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "isin": "ANQ103",
                        "label": "apple",
                        "swatch_value": null,
                        "products": [
                            121,
                            128
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                       "isin": "ANQ133",
                        "label": "milk",
                        "swatch_value": null,
                        "products": [
                            122
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "isin": "ANQ142",
                        "label": "coconut",
                        "swatch_value": null,
                        "products": [
                            130
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "isin": "ANQ123",
                        "label": "cherry",
                        "swatch_value": null,
                        "products": [
                            126
                        ]
                    }
                ];

  var filtered = data.where((e) => data2.contains(e['isin'])).toList();
  print(filtered.toString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for

```
  final result = [];
  for(var item in data) {
    if (data2.any((item2) => item2['isin'] == item['isin'])) {
      result.add(item);
    }
  }
  print(result);
```